# Nginx : Images takes too long to load. (1sec to download a 50KB image)

Tags: nginx, performance, images

I just switched from Apache to `debian 7.6` `nginx` `php-fpm` and after running all kind of optimisations it seems that **it takes a lot longer than usual to display images** :

The application is extremely fast (PHP side), I went from 1sec load time, to <500ms, the only problem are the images takes too much time to load for no valid reason.

[image]

Examples :

*50KB => `800ms recieving`*

or sometimes, just for an `32x32 icon`, it takes `700ms` "waiting" before recieving.
It feels like a 56K modem displaying "progressivly" the images.

- My nginx vhost [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/tristanbes/f15e9269cf63b5a52340)
- My nginx configuration [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/tristanbes/ade26d83ce154f7d2630)

My guess would be that I screwed up some settings since the hardware is not suspected (2servers 8CPU Xeon, 32Gb Ram, 1Gbps network, load avg: 0.13, SSD servers)

The 2 server are load balanced, meaning that all images are randomly downloaded from one or the other server (no difference) for the same master request.

**PS: Before switching to nginx, we had bad hardware, bad network and still, the images were loading a lot faster than now.**

**Why the image are taking so long to load?**  An example can be found here (http://sarl-hensgen.fr/)

Comment: Would you be using a very high compression flag for gzip ?

Comment: In my config file posted in my question, you could see a `gzip_comp_level 6;` which seems pretty "standard" for the gzip compression level.

Comment: did you figure out what was happening? I'm having similar problems

Comment: I have the same issue.